# How do I only return my primary keys from a Firebase RTDB and not the rest of the data stored when using a get() in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, firebase-realtime-database

My menu item tree looks is shown below:

```
menuItem
        J1
           -description:"Tasty milk shake!"
           -img:"assets/images/milkshake.JPG"
           -itemName:"Milk Shake"
           -price:20
           -varieties
                    -var1:"Chocolate"
                    -var2:"Vanilla"
                    -var3:"Strawberry"
```

I want to get just the item IDs (J1, J2, J3 ect.) but not all the information such as 'itemName'

```
final DatabaseReference _dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();
        final items = await _dbRef.child('menuItem').get();
        if (items.exists) {
          String? itemID = items.value.toString();
        }
```

`items.values` returns all the information for an item  and `items.key` returns only 'menuItem'.

How can I just get the IDs only?

Answer (score 2):

With the Realtime Database queries done via the Client SDKs are *deep*: **They always return the entire subtree**.

This is a key difference with Firestore for which queries are *shallow*: They only return documents in a particular collection or collection group and do not return subcollection data.

However, with the Realtime Database REST API you can use a query parameter named [`shallow`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database#section-param-shallow), which "limits the depth of the data returned at a location". I've never used it but it seems that it will fulfill your requirement.

---

Another solution would to denormalise your data and maintain, in parallel to the menu items, a list of menu IDs in a specific DB node.

Comment: Thank you, I will check it out. Do you think a Cloud Firestore database would be better suited for a food ordering app?

Comment: This is a vey broad question, depending on many factors, therefore it’s hard to answer based on your initial question. You’ll find a comparison page on the doc: https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/rtdb-vs-firestore

Comment: While Firestore read operations are shallow, it also doesn't have the option to get just the ID of its documents without also getting the data.

Answer (score 2):

As Renaud explained in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73175842/209103), all read operations in the Firebase Realtime Database SDKs return complete branches of the tree, and can't be used to just read the keys.

That said, you can use just the keys from the data you read with:

```
final DatabaseReference _dbRef = FirebaseDatabase.instance.ref();

final items = await _dbRef.child('menuItem').get();
items.forEach((child) => {
  console.log(child.key);
})
```

The above will still retrieve the entire `menuItem` branch of your database, but only show the keys under that node (so `J1` from the sample you shared).